# Creating subnet per availability zones in Azure using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-network

I am trying to create subnets per availability zones in Azure using terraform. I am using the code below to create a subnet.

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "public_subnet" {
  name                 = "public_subnet"
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.terraform_rg.name
  address_prefix       = "10.20.10.0/24"
}
```

My requirement is possible in AWS. Since I am new to Azure I am not sure whether it is possible to do the same in Azure. It would be great if some one render their hands to help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The azure subnet is not a [Zonal service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/availability-zones/az-overview#availability-zones)(where a resource is pinned to a specific zone), refer to [Azure services and regions that support Availability Zones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/availability-zones/az-region). So you need to create the specific support services per availability zone.

For example, you can create an Azure VM or Azure public IP per availability zone.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "east us"
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  name                = "acceptanceTestPublicIp1"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku = "Standard"
  zones = ["1"]

}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefix       = "10.0.2.0/24"
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  name                = "example-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.example.id
  }
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                = "example-machine"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  size                = "Standard_F2"
  zone = "1"
  admin_username      = "adminuser"
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.example.id,
  ]

 admin_ssh_key {
    username   = "adminuser"
    public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
  }

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}
```

If you're interested in the `zone` option, you can look at this [open issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3810).